# XCUITest: Interacting with table with many cells

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing

I have a `UITableView` with a search bar. The table can contain thousands of cells. Performance is fine, since only cells on-screen are actually fetched/rendered.

I'm trying to interact with the tableview using a UI Test, even trying to tap the search bar doesn't seem to work properly:

```
app.tables.searchFields["identifier"].tap()
```

Will cause the app to become unresponsive (100% CPU and ever-rising memory). When I do the exact same thing with only a small set of cells, it works just fine.

My guess is, some part the stack is fetching all the cells to query through. 
Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Nope, also filed a radar, also no luck there

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help to use firstmatch

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementtypequeryprovider/2902250-firstmatch

> When you call firstMatch, XCTest stops traversing your app's accessibility hierarchy as soon as it finds a matching element, speeding up element query resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Its also possible to use element(boundBy: Int):
**https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery/1500842-element**